# C bitfield bit order issue

Tags: c++, c, byte, bit, memory-address

I'm trying to build the bitfield flags of a DNS query and I'm a bit befuddled by the order of the bits i'm printing out as a way to test my DNS header.

So my struct for the DNSHeader is as follows:

```
typedef struct HEADER
{
....etc
unsigned char QR :1;
unsigned char OpCode :4; 
unsigned char AA :1; 
unsigned char TC :1; 
unsigned char RD :1;
.....etc etc
} DNSHeader ;
```

So as you can see, all these flags added together should take exactly 1 byte.  And RD should be the last bit of the byte.

However, when I set RD = 1, with rest = 0, I go and print out the byte, I get this: "80" in Hex, which is 10000000 in binary.  I did some further experiment and set both RD and QA = 1, and I get "81", which is 10000001, so this means the order of the bits are exactly reversed.  But if you look at the declaration of the struct, I wasn't expecting the reverse of the bits.  What is going on here?

Comment: The order of the bits is implementation defined. So using bitfields is not portable, and there is no basis for expecting the bits to be in any particular order.

Comment: @user3386109 so are you saying the compiler will interpret the fields just fine?  For example, when I send this DNS query header, the DNS Server will interpret the order of the fields as I defined it in my struct?

Comment: You're being told that the ordering of the bits in a bit-field within a storage unit for the bit-field depends on the compiler (but the compiler is strongly influenced by the ABI for the platform it compiles for).  The standard imposes no requirement on whether the first mentioned bit is the MSB or the LSB.  There are a lot of other things about bit-fields that the standard leaves implementation defined.  You can write code to work correctly with your compiler, but moving to a different system may require reworking the definitions of the bit-field.

Comment: If you look at these structs in header files designed to be used by many implementations, you'll see that they have swapped the order of the bitfields `#ifdef THIS_AND_THAT` ... `#else` ... `#endif`

Comment: For the rules in C11, see [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1), especially ¶4,5,9-15.  Note that when the data is sent over the wire to a DNS server, it will get the bits in an appropriate order so that if you send a byte containing 0xA5, the DNS server will receive 0xA5.  How that's interpreted depends on the network protocol, but the protocol specifies what 0xA5 means, and both ends understand that common meaning.  How you achieve the result with bit-fields varies, though.

Comment: got it thanks everybody!